# Returning a conditional type without doing unsafe cast or using `any`?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible in TypeScript to implement the body of this function without doing a non-typechecked `as` cast or using `any`?

```js
const f = <T extends string | RegExp>(t: T): T extends string ? T : 'REGEX' => {
  // return t instanceof RegExp ? 'REGEX' : t;
  // return typeof t === 'string' ? t : 'REGEX';
}

// These should typecheck.
const a: 'a' = f('a')
const b: 'REGEX' = f(/a/)
```

In TypeScript 4.1.3, the first attempt throws this error:

```
Type 'T | "REGEX"' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? T : "REGEX"'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? T : "REGEX"'.
    Type 'string | RegExp' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? T : "REGEX"'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? T : "REGEX"'.(2322)
```

The second one throws:

```
Type '(T & string) | "REGEX"' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? T : "REGEX"'.
  Type 'T & string' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? T : "REGEX"'.(2322)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAPAFRgUwB5U2AEwhmgCcBLMAcxgB8YAlTKgUWwAcA+ACigC4YaAJQCMOPIWJlKNAPyCYAgOQMWAcRYANJUk4wA3gCgYMAPSmYpTFACupMDFiVoAQzDBMIBE1YcY8lXUtHQEoAG5jS2s7BygAT3ZPBFhEVJglaWodeVhlVQ1tCIBfQ0NzQQALTAhMEgqQGwAbAkcEzGAq4ABrADpDUEhYF2UXHWQ4biVRoQiB6BgAIzyg7SR4blMXUxmgA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get something past the type checker without unsafe casts. It seems to be correct for me, but if anyone spots any error, please comment!

```
type F = {
  <T extends string>(t: T): T;
  (t: RegExp): 'REGEX';
}

const f: F = <T>(t: T) => typeof t === 'string' ? t : 'REGEX'

// These should typecheck.
const a: 'a' = f('a')
const b: 'REGEX' = f(/a/)
```